# PayPal checkout solution confusion

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to figure out exactly what payment solution to use for my site.

I would like to do the same thing as Spotify (https://www.spotify.com/us/freetrial/ - You'll need to login to see it), allowing users to choose whether they want to pay with PayPal or use a credit card and then taking them to a payment selection screen (on PayPal), then returning them to my site to click confirm and buy.

I am already paying for recurring payments (even though I've yet to use it) and am unsure if that is applicable here. I have also integrated express checkout but I don't know if it will allow recurring payments.

**EDIT:** Do I need a separate token for recurring payments? Do I have to use the old recurring payments checkout screen? How can this be done as efficiently as possible, like Spotify? Here are my efforts to create a recurring payments profile after express checkout: http://pastie.org/private/sakzopltnwfv93wwmduqq

**Diagram:**

Select Buy & PayPal (subscription) --> Choose Payment (on PayPal) --> confirm & pay (my site)

This is what spotify's checkout looks like (It wouldn't say update for first time users):
[image: PayPal Spotify Checkout]
Are they using recurring payments + express checkout? I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Yes, to me that looks like Express Checkout.  You don't need a separate token.  You'll call SetExpressCheckout and include the billing agreement parameters.  Specfically, L_BILLINGTYPEn would need to be set to recurring payments.  The documentation I linked to in my original answer covers the use of the billing agreement parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get this done with Express Checkout + Recurring Payments.  That said, if the person chooses credit card when setting up a recurring payment they will have to create a PayPal account.  If they're paying a non-recurring checkout then they could use the credit card option without creating a PayPal account.

You mentioned that you're already paying for recurring payments..??  Are you referring to Payments Pro?  If so, you don't need to pay for that to use EC + RP.  Pro is only necessary if you want to process credit cards directly on your site without ever redirecting to PayPal.  This can sometimes make things seem a little more professional and would also give you the ability to let people setup recurring payments without creating a PayPal account when using a credit card.

When using EC you just need to make sure to include the billing agreement parameters in order to get a token back that will work within CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.  Refer to the [SetExpressCheckout API reference](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp) for more details on that.

This is kind of old now, but is still useful.  Take a look at this [sample express checkout set of api calls](http://angelleye.com/temp/sample-set.php).  You'll notice it uses the same token throughout all of the calls.

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly, I've added a pastie above detailing my effort to add recurring payments post EC.

Comment: Check the link I added to my answer.  It's a sample of Express Checkout call flow to setup a recurring payments profile.

Comment: Quick note: Spotify doesn't appear to be using recurring payments. They appear to be using Express Checkout with a Billing Agreement. A billing agreement lets you call the DoReferenceTransaction API call at any time, with no set limitation on the amount to be charged. For more details see https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/express-checkout-reference-transactions - you need approval to use 'reference transactions', which you don't need for express checkout recurring payments.

Comment: By the way, here is a How-To guide for the same: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/how-to/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc

Comment: Then why am I paying for recurring payments, what does RP have that a Billing agreement doesn't?

Comment: You only have to pay for RP when using it with Payments Pro.  If you're just using Express Checkout then recurring payments / billing agreements are free other than transaction fees.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert I get an error saying `Error : Merchant not enabled for reference transactions` how can I enable reference transactions?

Comment: This would need to be enabled on your account; that's what I meant by "you need approval to use 'reference transactions'". Give PayPal customer support (or your account manager, if you have one) a call and they should be able to help you out.

Comment: Alternatively send me an email with your details and I'll get someone to give you a call back.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Spotify -you would need to build that option on your site. If the user chooses to subscribe with a credit card - use the recurring payments w/ direct credit card (see below). If the user chooses to subscribe with a PayPal account - use the recurring payments w/ PayPal Account (this is what Andrew is suggesting above in his response).

Here are the how-to guides:

For direct credit card subscriptions: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-pro/how-set-recurring-payments-profile-using-direct-payment

For PayPal Account subscriptions: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/how-to/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc

The APIs would allow you to do things like trial periods, setup fee, etc. For example here is a how to on building a freemium kind of model: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/how-to/ht_ec-freeTrialRecurringPayments-curl-etc

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you look at the pastie above? I'm trying to figure out how to add the recurring payments to EC. How do I do it?

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you use the Direct Payment method with recurring payments (they refer to it as DPRP) you'll have to pay $60/mo on top of your transaction fees.